# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in 'DentalProcedures' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. EF code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I will try to keep this one short. Any help is welcome and appreciated!

I have 2 classes that have a many-to-many relationship and their composite key class. When I'm creating a new "appointment" I want to pick "dental procedures" that are in the system.

All works fine until I reach the AppointmentRepository where I try to save the newly created appointment. The error is as stated.

I tried to add the

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

or

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

annotations above the `DentalProcedureId` property in the `DentalProcedure` class, but nothing works. Saved the changes and dropped tables, deleted all of the migrations etc.

DentalProcedure class:

```
public class DentalProcedure
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DentalProcedureId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The name of the procedure must be specified")]
    public string ProcedureName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The price of the procedure must be specified")]
    public decimal ProcedurePrice { get; set; }
    public bool isEnabled { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerProcedure> CustomerProcedures { get; set; }
    public List<AppointmentProcedure> AppointmentProcedures { get; set; }
}
```

Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime AppointmentStart { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime AppointmentEnd   { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ProcedureDescription { get; set; } 

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int WorkDaysId { get; set; }
    public WorkDays WorkDays { get; set; }

    public List<AppointmentProcedure> AppointmentProcedures { get; set; }
}
```

AppointmentProcedure class:

```
public class AppointmentProcedure
{
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }

    public int DentalProcedureId { get; set; }
    public DentalProcedure DentalProcedure { get; set; }

    public bool ProcedureAppointmentCanceled { get; set; }
}
```

Home controller:

```
 Appointment appointment = new Appointment
                {
                    AppointmentStart = model.AppointmentStart,
                    AppointmentEnd = model.AppointmentEnd,
                    Title = model.Title,
                    ProcedureDescription = model.ProcedureDescription,
                    CustomerId = Id,
                    WorkDaysId =  workkWeek.WorkDaysId,
                };

foreach (var proc in model.DentalProcedures)
{
    if (proc.isEnabled)
    {
        appointment.AppointmentProcedures = new List<AppointmentProcedure>
                        {
                            new AppointmentProcedure
                            {
                                Appointment = appointment,
                                DentalProcedure = proc,
                                ProcedureAppointmentCanceled = false
                            }
                        };
    }
}

_appointment.CreateAppointment(appointment);
```

And the error :

[image: Error message]

Thanks once more in advance.

PS: I'm  still learning so if I forgot to mention something, I apologize in advance!

Comment: From what I see it looks like you're loading the `proc` from the model. Either `Attach` it to the current context or load it again with the same Id (`db.Procedures.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.DentalProcedureId == id)`) and see if it helps. Most of the time in EF this error relates to something else which makes EF generate a code that tries to insert a record to the table with explicit Id

Comment: As @AlirezaNoori has mentioned it is due to assigning proc. once you use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] that will be generated by ef or db. Therefore, if you want to explicitly set the value, you must remove this annotation

Comment: @AlirezaNoori that did it! Thank you both, don't know how i missed something so obvious. Also I'm new here and cant see the "check mark" next to your comment to accept it. So that can be added as the second problem xd.

Comment: @Luka comments can't be marked as answer. I'll add an answer so you could accept it (for future reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework needs to track the object in the database so you need to either attach or (what I usually prefer to do) load it from the database. Here's the changed code:

```
foreach (var proc in model.DentalProcedures)
{
    if (proc.isEnabled)
    {
        //assuming the DBSet is called Procedures
        var dbProc = await db.Procedures.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.DentalProcedureId == id));
        appointment.AppointmentProcedures = new List<AppointmentProcedure>
                        {
                            new AppointmentProcedure
                            {
                                Appointment = appointment,
                                DentalProcedure = dbProc, //now set the loaded entity
                                ProcedureAppointmentCanceled = false
                            }
                        };
    }
}
```